# Wordpress Title Showing Wrong Name

Tags: wordpress

We have a wordpress site with a news page. Instead of the title showing as News at the top of the page, it is showing up as Blog.

Here is the page: http://tcsdesignreno.com/news/

I have checked in Menu, the actual Page on the backend, the SEO plugin we use (Yoast), and under Settings -> Reading but no where on the site does it show the title of this page as Blog.

Any ideas as to why this is getting changed? It may have been called Blog initially but I don't understand why it is still called blog.

We are using the Slab Theme in WP 3.4.2 on this site.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to check it out.

1. If you are using WordPress Menu located under Appearance > Menus
2. You can check the "Pages" for the title blog.

Comment: As I said, I checked under Pages and under Appearance > Menus. No where does it show any title named Blog. Not even in the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, one of my plug ins was setting the page title, which wasn't immediately obvious. I had to change what Yoast SEO set the title.